# using namespace of library inside symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have the following code in my controller , basically trying to use [this](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/README.md) library i have installed via composer

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

class MainController
{

    public function number()
    {

        $username = 'someusername';
        $password = 'somepassword';
        $debug = true;
        $truncatedDebug = false;

        $ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);


        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

however it gives me the following

```
Attempted to load class "Instagram" from namespace "InstagramAPI".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I have tried adding use namespace Instagram , but it didn't work

Comment: If you comment out the `Instagram` line, do you get the same error for `Response`?

Comment: Did you install using the composer require command shown in the docs? And has been pointed out below, there is no need to require autoload.php again since the framework takes care of it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I ran "composer require mgp25/instagram-php" and it all seemed to install.  Had to install the php bcmath extension.  And the instagram package installs a bunch of dependencies.  But it all worked as expected.  So double check that your installation had no errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/README.md the namespace is called `InstagramAPI`.

Try `new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);`.

Comment: that did not work too, i got

Attempted to load class "Instagram" from namespace "InstagramAPI".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: Make sure you can see the `mgp25/instagrap-php` folder in your `vendor` folder. Also `require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';` is not needed as symfony already handles this.